# Why can't I reference the project I created earlier from my wcf service class library?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, entity-framework-ctp5

> Warning   1   The referenced assembly "C:\Users\rzv\Desktop\CompanyAnalyse1.0\AnalyserModel\bin\AnalyserModel.dll" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project.

Why do I get this? AnalyserModel is a class library that uses Entity framework code first 5 to save data in a database. I tryed to create a new WCF service application that uses the methods in AnalyserModel. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the target framework from `4.0 client profile` to `4.0`.
you can do this on the projects properties page.

Comment: But according to his question, he didn't make any changes in the AnalyserModel assembly. He's saying he referenced it from a separate WCF service project.

Comment: @Rich - it is saying that AnalyserModel.dll is referencing the System.Web in the version 4.0 of the .NET framework.  apparently that is not part of the 4.0 client profile.  So he has to change his target framework to one that includes that file.  At least that's how I understand it.  I've seen that error/warning quite a few times and this always fixes it.